# The provided key element does not match the schema - only thru API Gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am having an issue with a Lambda function that updates DynamoDB.  I have been thru so many iterations of the code, but I am down to this one that does not make sense.  This code works in Lambda thru the Test functionality, but not in API Gateway.  The Cloudwatch logs state "The provided key element does not match the schema".

Table Name: GateData
Primary partition key: OpportunityId (string)
Primary sort key: none
GSI: SiteNumIndex (SiteNum)

I can do a GET just fine, but my POST wont work.

```
// Setting up our dependencies
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const https = require('https');

// Creating an eviornment variable to store DynamoDB table name
const TABLE_NAME = process.env.table_name;

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // Update the item, unconditionally,
    if (event !== null && event !== undefined) {
        var params = {
            TableName: TABLE_NAME,
            Key:{
                "OpportunityId": event.OpportunityId
            },
            UpdateExpression: "SET GateCode = :GateCode, GateKeypadZone = :GateKeypadZone, GateTimeZone = :GateTimeZone, UpdateFlag = :UpdateFlag",
            ConditionExpression: "attribute_exists(#OpportunityId)",
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                "#OpportunityId" : "OpportunityId"
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues:{
                ":GateCode": "" + event.GateCode,
                ":GateKeypadZone": "" + event.GateKeypadZone,
                ":GateTimeZone": "" + event.GateTimeZone,
                ":UpdateFlag": "true"
            }
        };

        docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));

              var response = {
                    "statusCode": 404,
                    "body": "failure",
                    "isBase64Encoded": false
                };
                callback(null, response);
            } else {
                console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

                var response = {
                    "statusCode": 200,
                    "body": "success",
                    "isBase64Encoded": false
                };
                callback(null, response);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        var response = {
            "statusCode": 401,
            "body": "nothing passed in event",
            "isBase64Encoded": false
        };
        callback(null, response);
    }
};
```

Comment: what does a `console.log(JSON.stringify(event,null,4))` look like in cloudwatch from both events (ie one from lambda test and the other through api gateway)

Comment: Chances are event.OpportunityId doesn't exist either due to using a Lambda proxy implementation or a mapping issue in API Gateway. But doing as LostJon suggests will show you one way or another, and show where OpportunityId is in the event object.

Answer (score 0):

So between this post and the AWS Support team you were all right.  Basically I needed to add this line in the code after I check if event.body is not null:

```
let body = JSON.parse(event.body);
```

I also added some other code to check if event.body was null, and returned some "valid" error codes.

```
// Setting up our dependencies
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const https = require('https');

// Creating an eviornment variable to store DynamoDB table name
const TABLE_NAME = process.env.table_name;

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // Update the item, unconditionally,
    if (event !== null && event !== undefined) {
        var OpportunityId;
        var GateCode;
        var GateKeypadZone;
        var GateTimeZone;

        if(event.body !== null && event.body !== undefined)
        {
            let body = JSON.parse(event.body);
            OpportunityId = body.OpportunityId;
            GateCode = body.GateCode;
            GateKeypadZone = body.GateKeypadZone;
            GateTimeZone = body.GateTimeZone;
        }
        else
        {
            OpportunityId = event.OpportunityId;
            GateCode = event.GateCode;
            GateKeypadZone = event.GateKeypadZone;
            GateTimeZone = event.GateTimeZone;
        }

        var params = 
        {
            TableName: TABLE_NAME,
            Key:{
                "OpportunityId": OpportunityId
            },
            UpdateExpression: "SET GateCode = :GateCode, GateKeypadZone = :GateKeypadZone, GateTimeZone = :GateTimeZone, UpdateFlag = :UpdateFlag",
            ConditionExpression: "attribute_exists(#OpportunityId)",
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                "#OpportunityId" : "OpportunityId"
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues:{
                ":GateCode": "" + GateCode,
                ":GateKeypadZone": "" + GateKeypadZone,
                ":GateTimeZone": "" + GateTimeZone,
                ":UpdateFlag": "true"
            }
        };

        docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));

              var response = {
                    "statusCode": 201,
                    "body": "failure",
                    "isBase64Encoded": false
                };
                callback(null, response);
            } else {
                console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

                var response = {
                    "statusCode": 200,
                    "body": "success",
                    "isBase64Encoded": false
                };
                callback(null, response);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        var response = {
            "statusCode": 202,
            "body": "failure",
            "isBase64Encoded": false
        };
        callback(null, response);
    }
};
```